# group by clause with specific column instead of all in toad for oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below query, which I just want to group by only for 3 column(subject_code,category_code,assrotment_code) since these are multiple entries.

I know I need to provide all the column which has select but I need these column in select and don't need at group by else output will not be correct. How to achieve this is there any other way to do this?

I can provide a snapshot why do I need this? the highlighted are duplicate in attachment, which I want to avoid, just need a single record for those.

Please suggest.

```
  select rts.MERCH_DIV_NUM, min(rts.DEPT_NUM) DEPT_NUM, bc.subject_code, bc.category_code,
         rts.ASSORTMENT_CODE, rts.CURR_PEND_QTY, 
         rts.CURR_PEND_AMT, a.assortment_desc
  from rts_subcat_dept_pending rts
  inner join bn_assortment a on rts.assortment_code = a.assortment_code
  inner join bn_category bc on substr(rts.assortment_code, 0, 4) = bc.category_code      
  group by bc.subject_code, bc.category_code, rts.ASSORTMENT_CODE
```

Comment: You're asking for something very unclear. Do you perhaps want the other column values from the same row that has the min() value? What if there are two rows having the same min() valu? A [mcve] would make this much clearer, for you and for us.

Comment: if you use window functions in  a CTE, you would need to specify all aggregation functions, if CURR_PEND_AMT has always the same value for one group you canuse MAX, MIN for that column, the same goes for all other columns that are not in the GROUP BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an Window function , you could circumvent the need to use aggregation functions for every column that is not in the `GROUP BY`

```
WITH CTE aS (  select rts.MERCH_DIV_NUM,
  rts.DEPT_NUM,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY bc.subject_code, bc.category_code, rts.ASSORTMENT_CODE ORDER BY  rts.DEPT_NUM ASC) rn
        , bc.subject_code, bc.category_code,
         rts.ASSORTMENT_CODE, rts.CURR_PEND_QTY, 
         rts.CURR_PEND_AMT, a.assortment_desc
  from rts_subcat_dept_pending rts
  inner join bn_assortment a on rts.assortment_code = a.assortment_code
  inner join bn_category bc on substr(rts.assortment_code, 0, 4) = bc.category_code      
) SELECT MERCH_DIV_NUM,DEPT_NUM,subject_code,category_code,ASSORTMENT_CODECURR_PEND_QTY
,CURR_PEND_AMT,assortment_desc FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Yes, Gotcha! I was looking for CTS expression only, but since I'm quite new for oracle, so was getting some issue, but I know how to do in sql.  Above query gives me the output want I want. Thanks a lot @nbk. https://stackoverflow.com/users/5193536/nbk

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to use an analytic function rather than aggregation:

```sql
select rts.MERCH_DIV_NUM,
       min(rts.DEPT_NUM)
         OVER (PARTITION BY bc.subject_code, bc.category_code, rts.ASSORTMENT_CODE)
         AS DEPT_NUM,
       bc.subject_code,
       bc.category_code,
       rts.ASSORTMENT_CODE,
       rts.CURR_PEND_QTY, 
       rts.CURR_PEND_AMT,
       a.assortment_desc
from   rts_subcat_dept_pending rts
       inner join bn_assortment a
       on rts.assortment_code = a.assortment_code
       inner join bn_category bc
       on substr(rts.assortment_code, 0, 4) = bc.category_code
```